# Can WikiMedia API return invalid JSON?

Tags: jquery, json, wikipedia-api

I have this result:

```
["asd",
  ["Asda","ASDIC","ASD","AsDB","Asdr\u00fabal Cabrera","Asdhoo","\u00c1sd\u00eds Hj\u00e1lmsd\u00f3ttir","Asdr\u00fabal Fontes Bayardo","ASD CF Bardolino Verona","ASD Fiammamonza"]
]
```

Retrieved from http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?&search=asd&action=opensearch&format=json

When I use getJson method of jQuery it can't parse the JSON above. Why?

Comment: It works fine for me. What exactly do you mean by “can't parse”? What actually happens? Maybe it fails because of [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)? Or some other reason unrelated to parsing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@jakeclarkson is right

I think this is a better way to do it:

```
        function onSuccess(data) {
            alert(data);
        }

        function onError(data) {
            alert(data);
        }

        $.ajax({
            url:"http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: 'callback',
            timeout: 5000,
            data: 'search=asd&action=opensearch',
            success: onSuccess,
            error: onError
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling the URL as you've written it using `jQuery.getJSON()` will result in an error due to the same origin policy mentioned by *svick* in the comment above.

What you need to do is add `&callback=?` to your URL. This will force jQuery to use **JSONP**. See the JSONP section of http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/. The following should work:

```
$.getJSON("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?&search=asd&action=opensearch&format=json&callback=?", function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```